# ¿Por qué aparece 'event is deprecated'? ¿Qué se debería usar en su lugar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vscode

Llevo tres años programando en js, casi siempre acompañado de `jQuery`. Cuando creo mis eventos suelo usar algo como lo siguiente:

```
$(document).on('keyup','myElement', function(){myFunction($(this),event)});
```

Y nunca he tenido problemas con hacerlo de esa forma, el problema es que hace algunas semanas me viene apareciendo en el `VSCode` editor una línea tachando la palabra **event**, y si se pasa el mouse por encima, aparece un texto que dice lo siguiente: `'event' is deprecated`.

Quisiera saber si es un problema de VSCode o si yo debería actualizar todos mis proyectos a la fecha, usando otra cosa en lugar de "event".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La función `myFunction()` recibe dos parámetros:

- El elemento que está haciendo disparar el evento **keyup**.
- Un elemento llamado **event** y es aquí donde tienes el problema.

Al no existir declarada ninguna variable **event** lo que está haciendo el navegador es acceder a `windows.event`. El uso de esta propiedad [está desaconsejado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) por lo que de ahí posiblemente venga el aviso de **VSCode**.

La solución más directa es declarar la variable *event* en la función anónima del evento **keyup** para que de esta manera la función interna `myFunction()` pueda hacer uso de ella (tal y como te recomienda el colega @hawks).

```
$(document).on('keyup','myElement', function(event) {
  myFunction($(this), event)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No pasas el parámetro `event` y la intellisense de VS Code te da una descripción errónea.

```javascript
$(document).on('keyup','myElement', function(event){
  myFunction($(this), event)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`event` inicia a ser obsoleto? deberías de tener mucho cuidado con tu código y evitar el uso de event de la forma que la utilizas, el resto de las respuestas anteriores indican claramente como solucionarlo.

#### Atención a lo siguiente:

> La propiedad de solo lectura Window.event devuelve el `Event` que está siendo manejado actualmente por el código del sitio. Fuera del contexto de un controlador de eventos, el valor es siempre **undefined**.

> Usted debe evitar el uso de esta propiedad en el nuevo código, y debe utilizar en su lugar el `Event` introducida en la función de controlador de eventos. Esta propiedad no se admite de forma universal e incluso cuando se admite introduce una posible fragilidad en el código.

[fuente: developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) [traduccion: propia]

En resumen: si antes lo hacías: `function(){myFunction($(this),event)}` seguirá funcionando pero en nuevos códigos evitemos hacerlo.